# Decoding ajax returned obfuscated image

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

Myfonts.com offers an open API that generates screenshots like so: http://apicdn.myfonts.net/v1/fontsample?id=1&format=png&text=Futura

I am trying to use the generated png file using a standard jQuery ajax request like so:

```
  $.ajax({
    url:'http://apicdn.myfonts.net/v1/fontsample?id=1&format=png&text=Futura',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

This is returning some super funky encoded png unicode like so `�PNG IHDR*��}PLTE�����������` <-- super abbreviated version

At first I tried appending the image as a data URI but that didn't work. Any idea what to do with this data to generate an image? Clicking on the link generates it.

Comment: Looks like a binary PNG file -- just save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="http://apicdn.myfonts.net/v1/fontsample?id=1&format=png&text=Futura" alt="look ma no hands" />
```